# Media Player Classic Homecinema display problem

Tags: windows-7, media-player, codec, media-player-classic

Recently I started having problems with Media Player Classic Homecinema. As far as I know, I didn't install any updates (or any new software actually). Also, I'm using default Windows 7 RC codecs; I didn't need to install any codec packs.

What happens is that when MPC is started, it opens fullscreen on secondary monitor. I guess that it opens some sort of error dialog, but I can't read it because MPC window is open above it. When I dismiss dialog (ESC or Enter) the movie starts to play, however no MPC GUI elements show (though I can click on them). When focus is moved to another app, MPC window resizes and becomes unresponsive. During the process, some window elements in other programs become garbled (but refreshing the window fixes that).

This happens on different video types (avi, wmv, flv) and affects both 32bit and 64bit MPC versions. At the same time, Windows Media Player works flawlessly.

I reinstalled MPC and replaced it with a newer version, with no effect whatsoever.

The only thing I can think of is to reinstall codecs, but how do you do that in Windows 7? Any ideas are welcome.

P.S. I'm not interested in other players.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried *completely* uninstalling and reinstalling MPC Homecinema? What I mean is, can you be 100% sure you have fully cleared / reset configuration options for it?

Could be a borked configuration option for the app, particularly if it was working before.

Comment: It could also be a compatibility issue. Maybe starting Homecinema in Vista compatibility mode might help troubleshoot the problem. Or running it as administrator, it may need rights somewhere.

Comment: Jeff, you gave me the idea; I deleted "Gabest" group of keys from registry, and reinstalled. There was also an option in installer to load previous settings; this time I made sure to have it unchecked. This fixed the problem. Thanks! :)